# Class Variable not Being Set

Tags: swift

This is a weird one. I have several classes so far in a test app and everything has been going swimmingly. However, I'm getting the error `EpisodePlayerController.Type does not have a member named episodeData` when I declare `otherThing` below.

```
import UIKit

class EpisodePlayerController: UIViewController {
    var episodeData = "Hi"
    var otherThing = episodeData
}
```

Tried restarting Xcode, restarting Mac, recreating the class, renaming the class, etc. At a loss. Might be a bug in my Xcode install, but I'd love to be wrong and not have wait for another release. ;)

Comment: Those are not class variables. They are instance variables. Use an `init`ializer to do that (or create a class variable/constant with the default data and then initialize the instance variables referencing the class variable).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because this view was being called via a segue, I wound up making the variable optional and then calling a function from the segue to set the optional variable and then trigger any function dependent on that variable:

```
import UIKit

class YourController: UIViewController {
    var yourData:NSString?
    func setYourData(value:NSString) {
        self.yourData = value
        dependentFunction()
}
```

A similar effect can be achieved using the `didSet` and/or `willSet` methods:

```
import UIKit

class YourController: UIViewController {
    var yourData:NSString? {
        didSet {
            // Dependent functionality
        }
    }
    func setYourData(value:NSString) {
        self.yourData = value
}
```

Also, for reference, the segue looks like this:

```
func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue!, sender: AnyObject!) {
    if segue.identifier == "yourSegue" {
        var destination:YourController = segue.destinationViewController as YourController
        destination.setYourData(someData)
    }
}
```

Comment: it feels like something is missing from your code sadly...
i tried in numbers variations but still can't get it to work. could you perhaps look it over ?

Answer (score 0):

This seems to solve the problem:

```
class EpisodePlayerController: UIViewController {
var episodeData = "Hi"
var otherThing = ""

    init(){
        otherThing = episodeData
    }
}
```

Take a look at [the property reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Properties.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH14-XID_323).

Comment: In my experience, you don't need (and can't have) the `func` keyword on init methods.

Comment: It doesn't seem to cause an issue in my case, but I will edit it out.

Comment: I think you're correct, @David. Removing `func` from the above `init` method results in an error regarding `super.init`. I started down this rabbit hole earlier but it seemed like a weird way to have to do something so simple.

Comment: @68cherries No, but it's got me thinking about another potential way of doing this. Will report.

Answer (score 0):

i think this code will help.

```
class Square: NamedShape {
        var sideLength: Double

    init(sideLength: Double, name: String) {
        self.sideLength = sideLength
        super.init(name: name)
        numberOfSides = 4
    }

    func area() ->  Double {
        return sideLength * sideLength
    }

    override func simpleDescription() -> String {
        return "A square with sides of length \(sideLength)."
    }
}
let test = Square(sideLength: 5.2, name: "my test square")
test.area()
test.simpleDescription()”
```

Comment: This results in the error `Expected declaration` when setting `Object.episodeData`.  :/

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that as far as Swift is concerned, none of your properties have values until the class is fully initialized.  Before that point, you can't interact with 'self' implicitly.  (this includes its properties and functions.)  I think your class is a good candidate for the `@lazy` attribute:

```
import UIKit

class EpisodePlayerController: UIViewController {
    var episodeData: String = "Hi"
    @lazy var otherData: String = self.episodeData
}
```

You could also include more complex stuff if you need to:

```
import UIKit

class ClassTwo {
    var episodeData = "Hi"
    @lazy var otherData: String = {
        // Additional parameters
        return self.episodeData
    }()
}
```

This way, you can access self because the property 'otherData' won't be called until 'episodeData' is fully initialized.